# Sum independent of the rearrangements of its terms?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it true, that in every concept of an infinite sum in a Banach space, encountered in an introductory functional analysis course, convergence is independent of the rearrangement of its terms ?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question -- what do you mean independent of rearrangement of its terms?

Comment: Typically absolute convergence is required.

Comment: There's also a notion of summable families in a Banach space, which is a weaker property than absolute convergence, but which is still independent of rearrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb R$ is a Banach space, and its concept of infinite sums is certainly *not* independent of rearrangements. The standard example is the alternating harmonic series $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, [which can be rearranged to have *any limit you like*, or none at all.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)